# Clicking on menu that link is not getting highlighted with color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added code for selected menu color to be changed but it is not affecting the change. Unable to add class `active` for selected menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
</script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="service.html">TECHNOLOGY SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="industries.html">INDUSTRIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="carporate.html">CORPORATE</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your script seems to run before html content is loaded. Does it work if you put <script> tag below your html code?

Comment: @danielarend - indeed - the script is run before the elements are created.

Comment: P.S: don't use `$(this).parent()`, use `$(this).closest('li')`. one day you might want to wrap your `a` elements into another tag, and jQuery will still work.

Comment: So, you question is: *"I click on a link, say `resources.html`, the browser redirects to that page and the clicked element has no class `active`"*, right? (see the problem? Perhaps reformulate your question - after you make sure your `<script>` tags are properly placed right before the closing `</body>` tag.)